# IE8 setTimeout with Anonymous function

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, settimeout

I have ajax code that changes the width of a div depending on the percent received and then loops the function again. The way I have it setup now works flawlessly in google chrome and FF but in IE8 (only IE i've tested it on) it freezes on the

Here is a screen shot of the debugger. Its showing where it was currently processing and it never left that spot ever. I've changes the timeout to 1000 and 1 didn't make difference.

Comment: onSubmit is supposed to be hooked up to a form.

Answer (score 1):

`onSubmit` is an event handler, and you're only delaying the function by 1ms, my guess is that Chrome & FF are ignoring this code, and IE is failing on it because IE is stupid.

**EDIT** oh yah, IE doesn't bubble onSubmit like everybody else because IE is stupid.

**EDIT2** whole code for OP here: http://pastebin.com/t8vdK8B2

apparently `onSubmit` is the name of a function in this code, it is also an event handler. Since functions are not polymorphic this should overwrite, but since it's an event handler I'm not sure.

**Edit 3**

Ok, so this `onSubmit` function should work and leave the event handler alone, but I suggest changing this functions name, what it looks like you're doing is trying to pass a variable to the function within a `setTimeout` you can do that like this:

```
setTimeout(onSubmit,1,id);
```

Comment: lol Sorry I think I chose a bad name for my function. Here is the whole code. pastebin.com/t8vdK8B2

Answer (score 0):

The onSubmit event doesn't bubble up in IE so you need to add the on submit event to the form directly.  E.g:

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("formToSubmit").onSubmit(upload_id); }, 1);
```

[Here are details](http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/submit.html) of browsers support of the submit event.